# Same query in Solr - producing different results when done through SolrNet

Tags: solr, solr4, solrnet

I am doing two very identical queries into Solr for the same search term, it gives me different results. Actually one is done using Solr Admin interface and another is using SolrNet - Client library.

Can anyone give me any explanation why this is happening, or what's wrong and how to fix. I'm out of idea!

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?q=black%20samsung%20android%20smart%20phone&wt=json&indent=true&defType=edismax&mm=75%25
```

Gives 816 results - this one is done using Solr Admin.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/select?q=black%20samsung%20android%20smart%20phone&start=0&rows=2&qt=edismax&mm=75%25
```

Gives 10224 results - this one is done using SolrNet.

I have total 80k + test products.

The correct result is produced by doing query by Solr Admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the second query might be qt=edismax! Do you have defined any request handler like that?

I would suggest you to define defType in extra param while querying Solr using SolrNet.